# How can I check the data in my database when creating the pyramid tutorial app?

Tags: python, database, pyramid

I am going through this tutorial
 http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/tutorials/wiki2/index.html
and I would like to see which pages I have added to my database. How can I view the database to see the files and entries in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a database file in your project directory with a .sqlite extension.  You can view it with the "sqlite3 myproject.sqlite" .  Once in the sqlite shell, you can type ".help" for more commands on viewing tables.

Comment: thanks. it was myproject.sqlite. SQLite Database browser is very useful for viewing the database btw